# create database using psql in shell script takes username as db name

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, psql

Following is the command I am using to create database in shell script

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" \
            -c "CREATE DATABASE $database;"
```

It throws error

```
FATAL:  database "POSTGRES_USER" does not exist
```

If I print $database and $POSTGRES_USER they show correct values but when this command runs with some reason the username is passed as the database name.

any clue what I might be missing?

======

```
function create_db() {
    local database=$1
    local query_databases="select datname from pg_database;"
    local databases=$(echo "$query_databases" | psql -Aqt)
//this do not return any database but I have one db
    database_exist=$(containsElement "$databases" "$database")
    echo $database_exist;

    if [[ "$database_exist" == 1 ]]; then
        echo "Database '$database' exists. Skipping."
    else
        echo "Create Database '$database'"
        psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username=$POSTGRES_USER \
             -c "CREATE DATABASE $database;"
    fi

}
```

taking reference from - https://github.com/mrts/docker-postgresql-multiple-databases/pull/10/files

Comment: It is a default. If **you don't supply** a database name, postgres uses the username as a database name. So: you should supply a database name on the commandline. (`postgres`,or `template1`)

Comment: @wildplasser shall I provide the name of the database which does not exists?

Comment: You should supply a database name that **does** exist. (`postgres` and `template1` (almost) always exist)

Comment: That resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `"` in the command.

`psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username $POSTGRES_USER -c "CREATE DATABASE $database;"`

Comment: I still get the same error, I have updated with my function definition in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using [`psql` terminal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) correctly. When using the long form of option, you need the `=` sign between the option and its value. Also the double quotes are not needed.

Consider:

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username=$POSTGRES_USER \
        -c "CREATE DATABASE $database;"
```

Comment: I still get the same error, I have updated with my function definition in the question.