# Username seen as database in psql command?

Tags: postgresql, psql

This question is similar to [create database using psql in shell script takes username as db name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000907/create-database-using-psql-in-shell-script-takes-username-as-db-name), but since that doesn't have an accepted answer I'm asking it again here. I've created a user with username `myuser` and password `mypassword`:

```
> psql
psql (11.5)
Type "help" for help.

kurt=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 kurt      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 myuser    |                                                            | {}

kurt=#
```

However, if I do `psql --username=myuser`, I get an error that `database "myuser" does not exist`:

```
> psql --username=myuser
psql: FATAL:  database "myuser" does not exist
```

I'm a bit confused by this error message, because according to `psql --help`, this is a user name, not a database name:

```
Connection options:
  -h, --host=HOSTNAME      database server host or socket directory (default: "local socket")
  -p, --port=PORT          database server port (default: "5432")
  -U, --username=USERNAME  database user name (default: "kurt")
  -w, --no-password        never prompt for password
  -W, --password           force password prompt (should happen automatically)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here is the version of `psql` I'm using:

```
> psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 11.5
```

Comment: Doesn't [@wildplasser's comment on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000907/create-database-using-psql-in-shell-script-takes-username-as-db-name#comment102407766_58000907) answer it perfectly?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. So if the username is not the same as the database name, you have to specify the latter explicitly, like `psql --username=myuser kurt` (where `kurt` is the database name) in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING)

> The default user name is your operating-system user name, as is the default database name

If you specify a username, that username is then also assumed as the default for the database name.

Comment: What is the password for default username database? I have tried my windows password but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After creating your new user, first you have to login using postgres user and create new database similar to your new created user. ex: if my new user is "david", I must create also database called "david" using posgtres user.After this you can now login using your new user created.